# Can't compile since SDK update

Tags: android, sdk

I recently did an SDK update through `tools/android.bat`. Now I have the following installed:

[image]

then I tweaked my build.gradle for a while to try to make everything work

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'

}
```

But now, everytime I try to compile, I have the following errors :

```
Error:(10, 42) error: cannot find symbol class AsyncTask
Error:(11, 42) error: cannot find symbol class Bundle
Error:(79, 28) error: cannot find symbol method execute()
```

etc... (24 similar errors in total) It seems my project no longer wants to import :

```
import com.google.android.gms.internal.os.AsyncTask;
import com.google.android.gms.internal.os.Bundle;
```

Do you have any idea where the problem could come from ?

Thank you

Comment: Where do those imports come from? `.internal.` is maybe gone now because it's internal and not intended to be used from anyone from the outside.

Comment: You were right. I dont know where this .internal. comes from. By removing those 2 lines, I can still use bundle and AsyncTask and I can compile. Problem solved. Thank you.